# how to get the CAPS LOCK (pressed Shift key) key state programmatically on IOS SDK?

Tags: ios4

I'm writing custom text editor with specific chars (non-english).

I know about property - autocapitalizationType to change capital, but before to viewing (changing) of char i NEED TO know about state of current keyboard.

And how to get the CAPS LOCK (pressed Shift key) key state of keyboard programmatically on IOS 4.0 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

As of the moment, there is no way to enable CAPs lock on the keyboard simply because you can't touch/modify Apple's APIs.  The only states you can receive from their keyboard are:

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```

The only way you can do something like that is to create your own keyboard class or find a custom implementation online.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
self.yourTexField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```