# Default Caps Lock Key On

Tags: ios, capslock

On iOS I have a field that will normally be all caps, but if the user wants to use upper/lower (or whatever) that should be their choice.  So, I would like to "default" the caps lock key to the on position.  I'm not finding any way of doing what seems like a simple and reasonable thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Like stated here [caps lock in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837041/how-to-get-the-caps-lock-pressed-shift-key-key-state-programmatically-on-ios-s) there is no way to enable caps lock on the keyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the CAPS LOCK (pressed Shift key) key state programmatically on IOS SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837041/how-to-get-the-caps-lock-pressed-shift-key-key-state-programmatically-on-ios-s)